# How can i hide second side/flip of Mesh CreatePlane in Babylon.js?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I want to hide second flip or side of plane of

> BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreatePlane

in babylon js

how can i hide??

Answer (score 0):

set `backFaceCulling` of mesh to `false`